# Is there an app for Mac thats lets me route all system traffic through a SOCKS5 server?

Tags: macos, network, vpn, proxy, socks

I'm already using the socks proxy option in the network settings.
The problem is, not all applications appear to be passing their traffic through the proxy.

Is there a simple SOCKS client for Mac which would create a system VPN configuration for routing the traffic?

Comment: Is setting a SOCKS proxy in System Settings not enough for this?

Answer (score 1):

One great option that kind of solves this problem is [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should try [TS-Warp](https://github.com/mezantrop/ts-warp), it uses PF-firewall for routing traffic. There is CLI and GUI app for mac.